# How to select 30 files and do a bunch of sed commands on them

Tags: sed

I want new copies of the files, so I want to do something like:

```
dir *.rb
foreach file
  make a copy of the file, e.g. 'blob.rb' to 'blob_processed.rb'
  do the 50 sed commands to process the blob_processed.rb file
end
```

How can I do this without creating 30 files that do these steps (the copy and then all the seds).
The seds are a little long but they work and they will be exactly the same for each file.  One example:

```
sed -i "s#require "selenium-webdriver"#require 'my_helper' #" blob_processed.rb
```

Comment: You will have to escape the `"` in the sed substitution command with a backslash (`\"`)

Comment: I got the changes you made to my post as a review myself, but if someone else would have made the review they probably would have rejected it. Normally you would add the modified acceptable answer to your question (with due credits), or if you come up with a vastly different answer, as a seperate answer to you own question. So watch out for that in the future.

Comment: +1 to your comment.  Yeah I was really on the fence about it.  I guess the thing I've seen (and not liked) is when the OP posts an answer using the knowledge from one of the answers given and the answer given was 90% there but the Answerer doesn't get credit.  you probably know what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you have some temp directory where you write your output, because otherwise you cannot run the command on `*.rb` twice without getting `blob_processed_processed.rb` files. You can always copy the output files from the temp directory when everything is finished and worked fine.
2. put the filenames in `""` to make sure you can deal at least with filenames with spaces in them.
3. Escape double quotes within the sed command with a backslash (`\"`)

The result would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p tmp
for i in *.rb
do
    out=tmp/${i%.rb}_processed.rb
    cp "$i" "$out"
    sed -i "s#require \"selenium-webdriver\"#require 'my_helper' #" "$out"
done
```

[Edit by Michael (OP) ]
This mostly worked although I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p tmp
for i in *.rb
do
  out=tmp/${i}
  cp "$i" "$out"
done
```

which kept the same filenames but put all the new files under tmp/

Comment: You could skip the `out=` and `cp` steps entirely with a little output redirection; if you use `sed` without `-i`, you could do something like `sed ... "$i" > "tmp/${i%.rb}_processed.rb"`

Comment: @evilsoup In principle you are right, but since there are going to be 50 or so `sed` commands (see OP) instead of just the one, you would probably have to create two intermediate files moving the output from one to the input of the next. And only have the last sed command output to the final destination. Doing that would be more error prone than having each line have the same format, and being able to add another `sed` to the end of that list without having to take special care.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it pretty well exactly like that:

```
for i in *.rb
do
    cp -- "$i" "processed_$i"
    sed -i 's#require "selenium-webdriver"#require '\''my_helper'\'' #' "processed_$i"
done
```

Also, if you don't mind it being the original file whose name changes, you can just use seds ability to back-up files before modifying them:

```
sed --in-place=.orig 's#require "selenium-webdriver"#require '\''my_helper'\'' #' *.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put the sed commands into a file and pass that to `sed`. For some reason I can't make that work with the `-i`option but that should not be a problem since you are copying anyway. For example:

```
$ cat seds
s/require "selenium-webdriver"/require 'my_helper' /
s/foo/bar/
s/baz/bar/
s/hello/goodbye/
```

Then,

```
for i in *.rb
do
    sed -f seds "$i" > "processed_$i"
done
```